# How to rotate char a certain number of letters?

Tags: rotation, char

Im not sure on how to go about doing this, but how do I move from one character to another in the abcs a certain number of times from user input? How do I also keep it in a circle? (Like if the char is z, will the complier know that it should go to a and start again?)

Thanks in advance

```
int encode( int ch, int shift );

  printf( Move the characters to the right or left? "%c/n" );

if ( right ){

    printf ( Rotate right by how much? "%i/n");
    scanf ( "%i" );
        if ( %i >= 1 ){
            %i++;
        } else if ( %i <= 1 )
            %i--;
    }


} else if ( left ) {
    printf ( Rotate left by how much? "%i/n" );
    scanf ( "%i" );
        if ( %i >= 1 ){
            %i++;
        } else if ( %i <= 1 )
            %i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have little programming experience based on your code, so I will explain in detail how this **simple** problem is solved.

I wrote the code in C language:

```cpp
char encode(char letter, int shift){

    char direction[6];

    printf( "Move the characters to the left or right (left/right)? ");
    scanf("%s", direction);

    if(strcmp(direction, "left") == 0){
        if((letter - shift) < 'A')
            return (letter - shift) + 26;
        else
            return letter - shift;

    } else if(strcmp(direction, "right") == 0) {
        if((letter + shift) > 'Z')
            return (letter + shift) - 26;
        else
            return letter + shift;

    } else 
        printf("UNKNOWN COMMAND!\n");

    return letter;
}
```

Check the line where it says:

```cpp
if((letter - shift) < 'A')
```

This means that if you shifted **below 'A'** you need to **add 26** (numbers of letter in the alphabet) to get to the correct letter.

Same thing applies here, but you check if you shifted **above 'Z'** so **deduct 26** to get to the correct letter:

```cpp
if((letter + shift) > 'Z')
```

Else if you are in the boundaries of 'A' and 'Z' just add/deduct shift to the current letter.

I showed you an example on upper case letter but the same thing applies for the lower ones.

Comment: If you think I have answered your question, please close the thread by marking the question as accepted.